# Django form errorlist render position

Tags: django, forms

When I display a form with errors using {{ f.as_p }} , the errorlist ul always comes first then the label and input field. For example:

```
<ul class="errorlist">
<li>This field is required.</li>
</ul>
<p>
<label for="id_content">Content:</label>
<textarea id="id_content" class="required error" name="content" cols="80" rows="10"/>
</p>
```

I know you can use

```
{% for field in f %}
<p>{{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}</p>
{{ field.errors }}
{% endfor %}
```

To change the errorlist ul position after label and field, but I want directly use f.as_p, f.as_table or {{ f }}, because it's simple and easy, especially when I have to show a lot of forms.

So the question is: Is there a way to make the errorlist ul shows after the field part by default?

Comment: It would be nice to define this in the form object, but I don't think there is such option.

Answer (score 8):

The loop I always use, which is fairly generic but very customizable is this:

```
{% for field in form %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ field.label_tag }}:</td>
    <td>
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <img class="tooltip" title="{{ field.help_text }}" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/icon_help.png">
        {% endif %}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Between table tags ofc :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way that will considerably ease this effort is subclassing Form (and ModelForm) in such a way that a new method is implemented to render output via an html template. How to do this is described [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/TemplatedForm).

Comment: This answer saved my life.  For the newest version of Django, you should use [this for passing a context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/upgrading/#django-template-loader).  Also note that ```{{ field.errors }}``` renders the error as ```ul```.  Loop through the errors to get each individual error.

Answer (score 1):

Form.as_p() is just a method in the Form class. Just create a new class that inherits from Form and copy-paste the as_p method and change it to your liking. Then anytime you make a new form inherit from your form class instead of Django's.

Answer (score 1):

I use jquery appendTo to move all errorlist ul elements after the django fields element. It doesn't need any work to render the html but adjust the django default html by jquery to fix your need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.errorlist").each(function(index){
        $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you output the form, my error list gets dropped down to the bottom of the form, no good.