# Django-crispy-forms change radio button error rendering

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

When an error is rendered for a non-radio button, I see this:

```
<div id="div_id_field_a" class="control-group error">
  <label for="id_field_a" class="control-label ">Field A</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select class="select" id="id_field_a" name="field_a">
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <span id="error_1_id_field_a" class="help-inline"><strong>Select one</strong></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When an error is rendered for a radio button, I see this:

```
<div id="div_id_field_b" class="control-group error">
  <label for="id_field_b_0" class="control-label ">Field b</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <p id="error_1_id_field_b" class="help-block"><strong>Enter a value</strong></p>
    <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="field_b" id="id_field_b_1" value="True">Yes</label>
    <label class="radio"> <input type="radio" name="field_b" id="id_field_b_2" value="False">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the error message to appear after the radio button controls, which is what happens when a combo box used?  Or at least not render the error inside a `p` tag and instead a `span` tag?

Here's how I render the form:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<form id='main-form'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% crispy form form.helper %}
</form>
```

and the form:

```
class MyForm(ReoBaseForm):
  field_b = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')),
    label='Field b', widget=forms.RadioSelect())

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_tag = False
```

Comment: I ended up not using crispy and used this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1221965/2233706).